# How to wait for user response for a limited time else proceed with script in shell

Tags: shell

I am trying to set up a shell script where some default arguments are pre-assigned and the user is prompted to press any key to change those default options. If no response is provided, the script should proceed with the default arguments in say 'x' seconds.

I have seen some responses using seconds in a while loop but i am guessing there could be something easier than that.

I want some like:
1) Show default arguments to user
2) Ask for any response if they want to change it. If no response is received in the desired time frame, proceed with default arguments

Need help with step (2)

Comment: See `help read`, option "-t". The caveat here would be that if timeout expires while user is typing, then it will be indistinguishable from just timeout.

Comment: use the timeout command http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html